# $\mathrm{Rad}(L)$ is contained in all maximal solvable subalgebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra and $\mathrm{Rad}(L)$ its unique maximal solvable ideal.

> **Problem:** Show that if $B$ is a maximal solvable subalgebra of $L$ (i.e. a Borel subalgebra) then $\mathrm{Rad}(L)\subseteq B$.

I am not sure why. We know that $\mathrm{Rad}(L)$ is a solvable subalgebra, so it is contained in at least one maximal solvable subalgebra. But why all of them?